# In Python, how do I replace certain integers in a list with other integers?

Tags: integer

I'm new to Python.

I have a list of numbers: lst=[1, 7, 2, 10, 20, 4]

I'm trying to replace the top three numbers in the list (7, 10, and 20) 
with their respective halves 3.5, 5, and 10.

This is the code I have so far.
I could calculate the halves but don't know how to replace numbers in a list.

lst=[1, 7, 2, 10, 20, 4]

maxvalue1 = max(1, 7, 2, 10, 20, 4)
print(maxvalue1)

maxvalue2 = max(1, 7, 2, 10, 4)
print(maxvalue2)

maxvalue3 = max(1, 2, 4, 7)
print(maxvalue3)

Halfofmaxvalue1=maxvalue1/2
print(Halfofmaxvalue1)

Halfofmaxvalue2=maxvalue2/2
print(Halfofmaxvalue2)

Halfofmaxvalue3=maxvalue3/2
print(Halfofmaxvalue3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 23, 1, 312, 123, 121]

# sort the list so that the largest are first
list = sorted(list, reverse=True)
# get the 3 largest
max3 = list[0:3]
# if the value x is one of the largest divide it by 2, else keep it the same
l = [x//2 if x in max3 else x for x in list]

print(list) # before replacement
print(l) # after replacement
```

Output:

```
[312, 123, 121, 23, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[156, 61, 60, 23, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```